# Python web crawling using Scrapy unable to fill form

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to crawl this site which requires me to fill the form with the postal code  to reach stores info.
the website: https://www.aldi-sued.de/de/filialen.html

I have written following code but don't know whats wrong. Please help:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import logging
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from ..items import StoreItem

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class StoreSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "aldib"
    start_urls = ["https://www.aldi-sued.de/de/filialen.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url="https://www.aldi-sued.de/de/filialen.html",
                                 formdata={"search": "38644"},
                                 callback=self.parse_stores)

    def parse_stores(self, response):
        for store in response.css('div.dealer-list > div.dealer-item-content'):
            name = store.xpath("span.dealer-name > strong::text").extract()

            sl = ItemLoader(item=StoreItem(), selector=store, response=response)
            sl.add_value("Name", name)
            yield sl.load_item()
```

I suspect about there are 2 forms in website that one for site search and one for store search and I unable to choose the which one on the first code. So I changed the request part with

```
    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                               formid="storeSearchForm",
                                               formdata={"search": "38644"},
                                               callback=self.parse_stores)
```

At the end I still cannot to reach the name of the stores in that postal code.